# How to have Multiple DataFields?

Tags: garmin, connectiq

Is there any way to have multiple `DataField`s given just one app.

I have two use cases for this:

1. DataField A uses an intermediate calculation that I want to expose as DataField B
2. I want to show the average value of DataField A

I want to avoid having 3 different apps, as that would incur a higher performance (memory and execution time) cost.

Comment: Sebastian, did you manage to find a solution to this? or did you package as 3 different apps?

Comment: @joneswah I stopped lokking after I got the answer from the Connect IQ team. It's unfortunate that such a simple use case is not easily supported.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in activities (e.g. Running, Biking, etc.) can typically use three or more Data Fields depending on the device. For example, a vivoactive is set at a static three fields for a given activity, while a Forerunner 920XT can display a single field, or multiple fields within an activity.

Connect IQ Data Fields are unable to share data, so you would either write a single Data Field that displays multiple values (those from your hypothetical DataField A and DataField B), or write two independent Data Fields: DataField A that does your intermediate calculation, and DataField B that also does this calculation plus additional calculation. This removes the complication of *dependencies* between Data Fields that could potentially complicate things for both the user and the developer.

Another option is to write a full Connect IQ Application instead of a data field. This is used in lieu of a built-in activity, and provides a lot more flexibility in what can be displayed during the activity. Of course, writing an Application may be more complex than a Data Field. (You can learn more about the different app types on the [developer site](http://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/what-you-can-build/).)

Comment: It is unclear from your response or the documentation whether a single app can offer a user multiple data fields? Your first suggestion seems clear that you could include a composite string result in the compute() "val1 - val2" (that doesnt really suit our idea) but your second suggestion implies there is a way to write two independent Data Fields but it is unclear whether we can package them in the same iq/prg file or if this requires us to create/market 2 almost identical solutions.